# PHP-DI DI\env() method doesn't work when using with symfony/dotenv or vlucas/phpdotenv

Tags: php-di

Since it's not recommended to use `getenv()` and [symfony/dotenv](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv), [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) have disabled it by default, how is it possible to configure DI\Definition\Resolve\EnvironmentVariableResolver to use custom $variableReader constructor parameter?

Comment: This is super annoying. I created https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/issues/754 in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to fixed with the recent merge: https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/pull/757

This was the work applied https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/pull/757/files

Comment: Great! Thank You!